# Server Stats piece of code updates the channel to undefined instead of the total members

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

so I've been creating a private bot for only one server that shows server stats and much more, but I have a problem; every time a user joins/leaves the guild, the bot updates a channel with 'undefined', but it's meant to be the number of members in total in that guild. Can someone help me? Here's the piece of code:

```
const serverStats = {
    guildID: '474658204475719701',
    totalUsersID: '578114537589309441',
};

client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    if (member.guild.id !== serverStats.guildID) return;
    client.channels.get(serverStats.totalUsersID).setName(` MEMBERS COUNT: ${member.guild.membersCount}`);
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
    if (member.guild.id !== serverStats.guildID) return;
    client.channels.get(serverStats.totalUsersID).setName(` MEMBERS COUNT: ${member.guild.membersCount}`);
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`membersCount` is not a valid property of a [Guild](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild). It's actually [`memberCount`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Guild?scrollTo=memberCount) (singular "member").

```js
member.guild.memberCount
```

This code will return the expected member count.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use for my server-info command:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");
module.exports.run = async (bot, message, args) => {
    let sicon = message.guild.iconURL;
    let serverembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setDescription("Server Information")
    .setColor("#ff0000")
    .setThumbnail(sicon)
    .addField("Server Name", message.guild.name)
    .addField("Created On", message.guild.createdAt)
    .addField("You Joined", message.member.joinedAt)
    .addField("Total Members", message.guild.memberCount)
    .addField("Bot Version", "2.4.4")

    message.channel.send(serverembed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope you still need him

```
const embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setDescription(` MEMBERS COUNT: ${message.guild.members.filter(member => !member.user.bot).size}`)
.setThumbnail(message.guild.iconURL)
client.on('guildMemberAdd', member => {
    if (member.guild.id !== serverStats.guildID) return;
    client.channels.get(serverStats.totalUsersID).send(embed);
});

client.on('guildMemberRemove', member => {
    if (member.guild.id !== serverStats.guildID) return;
    client.channels.get(serverStats.totalUsersID).send(embed);
});
```